# SC delete <service> does not work

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, command

I am running the sc delete command from C# code. But it always returns,

> [SC] OpenService FAILED 1060: "The specified service does not exist as an installed service"

I tried executing the code a number of times but I still get the same error. But If I go to the command prompt and execute the command, the service will be deleted successfully.

And yes, if I execute the command again on command prompt it gives me the same above error. So I want to know, why it does not delete from C# code, am I missing something?

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c sc delete 'myService'")
{
  RedirectStandardOutput = true,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  CreateNoWindow = false
};

var proc = new Process { StartInfo = procStartInfo };
proc.Start();

// Get the output into a string
var result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Did you read the `[delete]` tag's excerpt? It clearly says "*This tag is deprecated! Please use a more specific tag instead.*" Please read tags more carefully in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the single quotes. They don't work.

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c sc delete myService")
```

to handle the double quotes for a spaced service name then you need to escape them.

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c sc delete \"my Service\"")
```